# Plugin Wordpres que Trava Menu no topo da Tela

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Alguém poderia me indicar um plugin para wordpress que faça o Menu Travar no topo da tela quando faz a rolagem da tela para baixa.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vai um plugin que parece fazer o serviço : 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/mystickymenu/

Demo : http://wordpress.transformnews.com/plugins/mystickymenu-simple-sticky-fixed-on-top-menu-implementation-for-twentythirteen-menu-269

Comment: Valeu pela dica, obrigado. vou add e ver o desempenho

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/109492)

Comment: @celsomtrindade a pergunta solicita claramente uma indicação de plugin e minha responda corresponde exatamente a isso. Com um link para a página do plugin no repertório wordpress e outro para a página do plugin com uma demonstração.

Comment: Essa é a questão. Tanto a pergunta como a resposta estão fora de escopo.

Comment: @celsomtrindade nesse caso como podemos mudar isso ? Qual é o escopo ? Obrigado.

Comment: Nesse caso, quando a pergunta não está no escopo, é bom não responder, pois você pode receber votos negativos (como aconteceu).

Comment: @celsomtrindade obrigado pelos esclarecimentos. Porém ainda tenho dúvidas quanto ao que faz parte ou não do escopo em questão.

Comment: Dê uma lida [nesse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) =D Vai ajudar

Comment: @celsomtrindade tudo ficou claro agora. Valeu !